# Request Method GET returns wrong content length

Tags: java, android, http, connection

Hi i am using an `HttpURLConnection` that gets a `txt` file's content and i want to know the size of that file and i use the content length Method but it returns wrong value for example in this code the file's size is 17509 but it returns 5147 ?
so Any Help?
Thanks so much in advance :).

```
new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String path = parser.getValue(e, "txt");
                                URL u = null;
                                try {
                                    u = new URL(path);
                                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u
                                            .openConnection();
                                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                    c.connect();
                                    int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
                                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                                    final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    long total = 0;
                                    Log.i("p1",""+lenghtOfFile);
                                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                        total += count;
                                        Log.i("p2",""+total);
                                        bo.write(buffer, 0, count);
                                    }
                                    bo.close();

                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The content-length is a header set by the server.  I would check to make sure that your server is returning the correct content-length.  You can do that with cUrl:

```
curl -v http://path/to/file.txt
```

That should show you the headers that were sent and returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the http path is http://mrsoft.weab.eu/chagvalagar/topic1.txt

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround I can think of, is just ignoring the content-length and reading input stream until there's nothing left to read.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
int read = inputStream.read();

while (read != -1) {
   byteArrayOutputStream.write((byte) read);
   read = inputStream.read();
}

byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
buf = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```